# Should I copy controller, or use artisan:make controller?

Tags: laravel

I have this great doubt, if I copy and modify an existing controller in my laravel project vs create a controller with `php artisan make:controller MyController`, Is there any affected configuration files?  or is it normal to copy and edit my other controllers?

Comment: It is totally fine to copy paste a controller - using `php artisan` is just a way to make your coding easier. But it's up to you at the end to choose what fits you best 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a lot easier to do the official command

```
php artisan make:controller myController
```

I mean, it's what they are there for. I don't believe that hand-making a controller will have a negative effect but it's so much easier and safe to use the function that's already defined.

Answer (score 1):

many times in a controller you have a lot of logic that you want to reuse, IMHO sometimes it's worth manually copying the controller.